# Python -- f.write() limited arbitrarily?

Tags: python

I've written a module for testing a program, and it writes the test data to a text file. My problem is that file isn't anywhere near the size of my system RAM, but always cuts off before writing all the data. What exactly is going on?

Code snippet:

```
def test_del(tree, over=True):
    if over:
        log = open("testlog.txt", 'w+')
        log.truncate()
    else:
        try:
            log = open("testlog.txt", 'r+')
        except:
            log = open("testlog.txt", 'w+')
    lis = treeToList(tree)
    shuffle(lis)
    while lis:
        tree = delete(tree, lis.pop(0))
        log.write(str(write_tree(tree)))
        if tree:
            log.write("\n")
            for e in treeToList(tree):
                log.write(str((e, search(tree, e)))+"\n")
        log.write("-" * 80 + "\n")

    if "False" in log.read():
        print "There is an error in the test case. Refer to testlog.txt."
    else:
        print "No error in test case. Results stored in testlog.txt."
```

The function `treeToList()` converts a 2-3 tree to a list,`write_list()` returns a string representation of the tree, `shuffle()` is `random.shuffle()`, and `delete()` removes a given element from the tree. All of these functions are working properly.

Comment: And if you really want to do all of this stuff in memory, there's `io.StringIO` to provide a file-like in-memory object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `log.close()` anywhere.  Without that, you don't guarantee that the log is actually flushed to disk properly.

Try adding a `log.flush()` after each write line.  It'll slow your code down, but It should give the correct output.  You'll probably also want to `log.seek(0)` before you `log.read()` as well.

Comment: Yep, and the documentation on [`file.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) explicitly warns about this: "Due to buffering, the string may not actually show up in the file until the `flush()` or `close()` method is called".

Comment: That seemed to work in one case, but now I'm getting a strange output after the EOF, which SO can't seem to interpret, starting with `k_pasteN(`. Another case gave me a still stunted log.

Comment: The completed run seems to have been a fluke. I'm still getting cut off.

Comment: Consider using `with`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus -- I'm not sure that `with` is super helpful here since OP is writing to and reading from the same file.  `with` only helps to make sure things are closed, but it won't help you if you write, then seek back someplace else and try to read what you just wrote (which is why the explicit `flush` might be necessary).